# Check is it valid reset_password_token, Rails 5 devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using Rails 5 with `Devise`. I want when some1 make request for new password, then go to the URL to change his password, if it is not valid `reset_password_token` to return 404:

```
unless confirm_token.errors.empty?
  raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
end
```

For this I need to check is it GET parameter `reset_password_token` same as one in the table column `reset_password_token`.

There is a method for that `confirm_by_token`, but it is for validate email URL and checks column 'confirmation_token'.
Is there built in Devise method for checking is it valid `reset_password_token` or I need to create it ?

Comment: I found this: `https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/60`